# How To Detect Game Over in Top Down View Endless Runner Game in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm developing a game using Swift SpriteKit. All things have gone fine but the only thing made me freaked out is detecting Game Over. My game look like picture below, it is a top down view game.
[image]

The `Brown Color is Wood` and the `Blue Color(that one looks like water) is River`. If player step on river instead of wood then the game is over.

The problem is how can i detect it step on river. I have tried using SpriteKit Contact which is `func didBeginContact`. But it only get called when startup, after that it not calling anymore even i step on it.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you should mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

### There are two possible ways that came in my head.

#### 1. *In your touchesBegan* you do this.

> NOTE: This will not work if the player is able to Fall into the river without interaction. In addition to that it calls Game Over a bit to early.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

if wood.containsPoint(location) {
        } else {

    // Call Game Over func
    }}
```

#### 2. *In your update func* (This should work all the time)

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    super.update(currentTime)

if wood.containsPoint(Player.position) {
} else {
// Call Game Over func

}}
```

> **UPDATE**: The code should be working